# bookshelf js save() command not updating rows in postgresql db

Tags: postgresql, bookshelf.js

JS beginner trying to get a PostgreSQL DB talking to express.js through bookshelf.js.

github: https://github.com/duskyshelf/bookers-academy/blob/master/booker.js

```
var knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'pg',
  connection: "postgres://localhost/bookers"
});

var bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);

var User = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'users'
});

var bob = new User({id: 2});
bob.save()
```

bookshelf.js seems unable to add any content to the db.

Current error message is: "Unhandled rejection CustomError: No Rows Updated'

Answer (score 45, accepted):

When you create your model providing your own id, like in

```
var bob = new User({id: 2});
```

Bookshelf assumes it is an **update** operation, *not* an insertion. It sets the internal `isNew` attribute to false, and when `save()` is invoked, instead of `INSERT INTO user(id, ...) VALUES (2, ...);`, it executes `UPDATE user ... WHERE id = 2;`.

If there is no user with `id = 2` the update will *almost* silently **DO NOTHING**.

To force an insert you must change the save() to:

```
bob.save(null, {method: 'insert'});
```

Bookshelf save() [documentation](https://bookshelfjs.org/api.html#Model-instance-save) describes this behavior.

Comment: this had me for a bit, i was using `{ insert: true }`

Comment: I was providing my own id and it solved it for me as well since it was taking it as an update instead of an insert. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a User table using knex? One potential problem I can think of is that you do not have any logic that actually creates the table for your Postgres DB. Here is some sample code that will create a table in your database if it doesn't yet exist.

```
bookshelf.knex.schema.hasTable('User').then(function(exists) {
  if(!exists) {
    bookshelf.knex.schema.createTable('User'), function(user) {
      user.increments('id').primary();
      user.timestamps();
    }).then(function(table){
      console.log('Created Table:', table);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried your code, but I get the same error. I had a simpler version of that code originally, and I've also tried manually creating the table, all of which return the same error message.
    
Could there be any errors in my PG setup? I kept everything default for simplicity.

Answer (score -1):

```
new User({id: 2}).
 save().
 then((model) => {
  res.json({ success: true });
});
```

Comment: Overwriting the `id` attribute (assuming it's a primary key) will cause Bookshelf to attempt an update instead of an insert. This will throw an error if there's no existing record with that `id`.

Comment: sorry, I thought he was just trying to save data. I just tried to demonstrate to save data not updating. thanks for pointing it out otherwise it can misguide others.

Answer (score -5):

No no! new User returns a PROMISE! You can't use it like that.
Try

```
new User().save()
```

Comment: Not true. `new User` only instantiates the model in memory. Calling `save` *does* return a Promise. The OP's issue was specifying a primary key, which instructs Bookshelf to perform an update instead of an insert.